# How to set docker environment variables to my config.toml file

Tags: docker, go, toml

In my project I have stored all the configuration values in config.toml file. now I want to change these variables using docker environment variables. Is this something possible ?..... The project is in go lang(not sure if this info is required)

The content of the config.toml file is as follows->

```
[mqtt]
    Hostname = "localhost"
    Port = 9096
    ClientID = "mailer_ms"
    Qos = 1

    [database]
        Hostname = "localhost"
        Port = 5984
        Username = "root"
        Password = "root"
```

Expected Output->
the value of username, port and password gets changed based on docker environment variables.

Please help me :)

Comment: Are you trying to read environmental variables in your Go application, set via Docker or otherwise? (if so see [`os.GetEnv`](https://pkg.go.dev/os#Getenv)). If not can you please add further detail explaining what you wish to accomplish (I see you are using MQTT so [this example](https://github.com/eclipse/paho.golang/tree/master/autopaho/examples/docker) may be relevant; it uses docker + environmental variables + MQTT).

Comment: Yep that is good, but for that I have to change a lot of code, so I wanted to know if it will be possible to preform something similar in my config.toml file ?

Comment: Sorry - still not really sure what you mean. You could grab the data from the environment variables and then populate the `config.toml` using that data (before your program opens it) if you want (either in Go or using a shell script).

Comment: you can use ensvusbst in your entrypoint on that config file. Although it would be better practice to read the variables directly from your code.